# Как сделать резиновый Хэдер по высоте?

Tags: css3, html, css

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с очень серьёзной проблемой, необходимо сделать Хэдер резиновым по высоте. 
По ширине реализовал, необходимо сделать по высоте. Сложность в том что в Хэдере присутствует сплошная картинка.

Вот сам сайт http://gardencompany.su/

В данный момент на сайте Адаптивный дизайн. 
Для того чтобы Хэдер масштабировался при изменении размера окна и картинка была такого же размера я использую `background-size: 100%;`

Но у меня Хэдеру прописан height: 789px;

И при масштабировании сам хэдер остаётся такого же размера и картинка уменьшается, и контент соответственно стоит на одном месте.

Пробовал уже делать через `max-height` и `min-height`, но всегда почему то работает только `min-height`...

Прошу помощи, кто уже сталкивался с таким, как такое возможно сделать? Необходимо именно реализовать Резиновый хэдер по высоте.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее огромное Спасибо!

Comment: выделите проблему на jsfiddle, для картинки используйте сервис placehold.it

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать `background-size: cover`

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

http://jsfiddle.net/jsh9be6t/

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


header{ 
 background: url("http://natureandsport95.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/blagoustroistvo-plyazha-himki-big1.jpg") no-repeat center top;     
 min-height: 200px;   
 color: #fff; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

.row{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 10px;   
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="row"> 
       <h1>Но у меня Хэдеру прописан height: 789px;</h1>
       <p>Прошу помощи, кто уже сталкивался с таким, как такое возможно сделать? Необходимо именно реализовать Резиновый хэдер по высоте. 
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее огромное Спасибо!</p>
    </div>
</header>
```